AWS ssm-user with selinux need to switch context
I currently expose some ec2 instances to some users via ssm.  The instance assigns the selinux user system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0.  For audit purposes, I want to force users to sign in using their individual account which is assigned the selinux user staff_u.  I already have a script that forces users to switch to their user with su - <username>; however, they are not able to run sudo commands because they still have the selinux context from the ssm-user.  The error received is:
sudo: system_u:sysadm_r:sysadm_t:s0 is not a valid context

I tried using sudo -r staff_r -u <user> -s, but I get the same invalid context error.
It seems that what I need is to transition context from system_r to sysadm_r.  I've been trying to create a selinux policy for transitioning to the staff_t or sysadm_t domains, but haven't had any luck yet.  I'm pretty new to selinux, so I may be making some bad assumptions or miss-understanding the error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am trying to do this on rhel7 (I know, soon out of maintenance), but I've tested on AL2 and rhel8 and had the same issue.
Appreciate any help.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-preferences-run-as.html maybe you want to change the user that gets used for the sessions.  Looks like you can set it to one static value for all users, which sounds like what you want.

@erik258, thanks for the idea. One of the issue's I've had is controlling the ssm-user context.  I won't be able to use a static account, I need each user to have their own account/logs, but it might be easier to create a static user that has the same context as the end users and thus making context transition a non-issue.

Later on in the document ("Option 2"), it also describes how you can add the user name to the IAM entity that is executing the SSM Start Session.  It gets complicated.  How are you managing your users in the OS?  In IAM?  Are you using SSO or identity federation, or managing your users manually on instances / IAM users?

@erik258, users are internally managed using ipa.

Also, we use a provider to assign iam roles, we don't have iam users, so I don't think IAM would provide the necessary granularity for the user account on it's own.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/configuring-aws-systems-manager-session-manager-support-federated-users-using-session-tags/.  it's possible this won't apply to you as it's not the same exact thing, but I wouldn't give up too quiickly.  It comes down to getting a tag attached to the IAM Role that refers to a variable set by the identity provider, if I understand correctly.  Could be your identity provider can do the equivalent.

So, I had to put this aside for a bit for something more critical, but I picked this back up and have not been able to solve the problem yet.  I tried using runas, but even when I use an ipa user with runas support, the user gets same system_u selinux user even though ipa says it should be staff_u. I found some things that seemed to indicate that this could be a rhel 7 issue, but tested in rhel 8 and am having the same problem.
